# Executar rotinas em background

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma rotina para ser executado ao abrir meu sistema uma vez por dia, coloco um `panel` com uma mensagem para o cliente ver que está sendo processado, mas agora está levando bastante tempo para ser executado.

Minha ideia é colocar em *background*, fiz testes com *Thread* mas ela trava meu sistema.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso sem a necessidade de travar o usuário?

Comment: quando você usa uma thread o seu sistema trava? talvez você esteja usando errado, pode descrever melhor qual seria essa operação?

Comment: Minha rotina executa uma stored procedure no banco de dados para calcular juros de documentos. Hoje eu coloco um panel e travo o sistema para o usuário até ela terminar, mas em alguns clientes demora um certo tempo. Então quero colocar em uma thread ou algo parecido, as dicas que achei de como usar thread não funciona bem no meu caso, o sistema trava e só volta quando finaliza o procedimento.

Comment: Parece que a solução realmente seria utilizar uma thread, uma outra alternativa seria o seu programa utilizar um programa externo pra fazer a operação e aguardar o resultado dele em uma arquivo de texto por exemplo, seria como uma thread, o seu problema então são as threads, se puder postar como você está usando elas e quais tutoriais seguiu.

Comment: A forma como fiz foi baseado em tutorial da net, criando uma classe Thread e colocando o procedimento dentro do método execute. Você teria um tutorial sobre threads?

Comment: tem esse aqui: [link](https://simasware.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/criando-threads-com-delphi/), é bom que antes de aplicar ao seu problema você teste em uma aplicação simples pra ver como funciona.

Comment: Se a thread congela o sistema, possivelmente você a acionou com o método execute. Tem que ser com start. Outro detalhe é que a thread não pode usar a mesma conexão do resto do programa com o banco de dados, tem que ser uma conexão só pra ela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize TTaks de processamento em paralelo.

```
procedure executarrotina;
begin
  vg_Tarefas.Add(TTask.Create(procedure ()
  var vEmail : TEmail;
  begin
      vEmail := TEmail.Create;
      try
        vEmail.Assunto := pAssunto;
        vEmail.Destinatarios := pDest;
        vEmail.Mensagem := pMens;
        vEmail.Enviar;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(pMens);
        FreeAndNil(vEmail);
      end;
  end));
  vg_Tarefas[vg_Tarefas.Count - 1].Start;
end;
```

declare a variável

```
var vg_Tarefas : TList<ITask>;

uses System.Generics.Collections;
```

Muito importante: Nunca utilize comandos que mostre avisos, atualize edit, nesta rotina. Se quer performance, não atualize tela. Se precisa atualizar tela, atualize algo numa tabela e dispare evento no banco, que será mais eficiente.

Neste exemplo, estou enviando email em background (paralelo).